# Is it bad practice to have a method return a string inside another method?

Tags: c#

So, I'm writing some code for an assignment in my Data Structures class, and I was wondering if using a method return a value into another method is generally bad practice

```
public void PrintLocation(MarsLander ml)
{
    for (int i = 10; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} m: {1}", i * 100, WheresTheSpaceship(ml, i));
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

public string WheresTheSpaceship(MarsLander ml, int i)
{
    if (i == ((ml.GetHeight() % 100) + 9))
    {
        return " * \n";
    }
    else
    {
        return "\n";
    }
}
```

The `WheresTheSpaceship` method should return whether to print the location of the spaceship (the *) just indent down to the next line and return to the `PrintLocation` method to reiterate the loop. (This is my first question please go easy on me :) )

Comment: this is done all the time but its not a good method name.

Comment: This is okay because putting everything inside a single method IS the bad practice. This makes your code more loosely coupled.

Comment: It would be cleaner to have a call `GetRoundedLocation` that is called just once for the lander, and keep all the printing code together separate from the calculation code. As written, if the lander location was being updated on a separate thread it wouldn't work.

Comment: Consider using `private` as modifier for the method `WheresTheSpaceship`

Answer (score 1):

In general it is good practice to keep methods short and to have a specific purpose, otherwise they may be misused. (Your method determines whether the location should be printed and formats the output).
The method should return what it was intended for: If you want to ask whether the location should be printed, a more appropriate method would be:

```
public bool ShouldPrintLocation(MarsLander ml, int i)
{
    return (i == ((ml.GetHeight() % 100) + 9);
}
```

`PrintLocation()` would then actually print the location if that is necessary:

```
public void PrintLocation(MarsLander ml)
{
    for (int i = 10; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        string locationText = ShouldPrintLocation(ml, i) ? "*" : string.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} m: {1}", i * 100, locationText);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

To me it makes more sense to have the output formatting in `PrintLocation` as this method is intended to.. Print the location, as opposed to doing some logic/calculation

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad, if it's necessary.  It is practiced even by others.  Maybe just change the method name for your code, example `GetSpaceshipLocation(MarsLander ml, int i)`